# how to store selected items in an array from listview?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

how to put selected items from a `custom listview` with an `imageview` and `textview` into an array? Actually my `imageview` changes when selected.

how to store those selected items in `Array`?

Answer (score 2):

Better store the items in arraylist

```
ArrayList<View> arr = new ArrayList<View>();// to store list of selected views
ArrayList<Integer> positionArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();// to store list of selected positions
```

use `setOnItemClickListener` in listview.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            positionArr.add(position);
                arr.add(arg1);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If positionArr is created with <View>, you'd get an error trying to do positionArr.add(position) as position is not a View.

Comment: @Maximus, Thanks. i had made the mistake now i have modified

Comment: yeah.. positionArr.add(position); is showing error.what should i do bcz its created with view.

Comment: now i need to set the imageview in a if statement to store all these array..its showing error for me..   if(view.findViewById(R.id.vi).getVisibility()==ImageView.VISIBLE){

Comment: what does this code mean by? can you post sample code. do you mind accepting the answer?